# When trying to start VirtualBox, I get the following error: Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_NO_MEMORY)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

This is my first time using VB, version 6.1.38 r153438 (Qt5.6.2).

The host system is Windows 10 Home, version 10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044.

I am attempting to install Manjaro Linux on the VM (I made sure that the installation ISO is the first one in the boot order), but before even having the chance to install it, I get the error mentioned in the title.

I set base memory to 2048 MB, and virtual disk size to 128 GB. I made sure I had enough RAM and storage space. All other settings are default ones.

I made sure that virtualization is enabled in BIOS. I attempted to decrease virtual disk and memory size. I enabled EFI. I kept getting the exact same error. I couldn't find anyone having a solution to this exact error on Google (a solution was provided, but only for a Linux host).

The entire error says:

```
Failed to load R0 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VMMR0.r0: RTCrStoreConvertToOpenSslCertStack failed: \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0 (VERR_NO_MEMORY).
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_NO_MEMORY).
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)Component: ConsoleWrapInterface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Log:

```
00:00:04.551205 Log opened 2022-09-15T09:33:50.402431000Z
00:00:04.551206 Build Type: release
00:00:04.551209 OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:04.551210 OS Release: 10.0.19044
00:00:04.551210 OS Service Pack: 
00:00:04.738969 DMI Product Name: B85M-HD3 R4
00:00:04.743505 DMI Product Version: To be filled by O.E.M.
00:00:04.743518 Firmware type: BIOS
00:00:04.743529 Host RAM: 16284MB (15.9GB) total, 8317MB (8.1GB) available
00:00:04.743531 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
00:00:04.743532 Process ID: 10684
00:00:04.743532 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:04.745568 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:04.746080   None installed!
00:00:04.746915 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:04.747227 Qt version: 5.6.2
00:00:04.749398 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:04.906575 PDMLdr: pdmR3LoadR0U: pszName="VMMR0.r0" rc=VERR_NO_MEMORY szErr="RTCrStoreConvertToOpenSslCertStack failed: \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0"
00:00:04.906617 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\PDMLdr.cpp(733) int __cdecl pdmR3LoadR0U(struct UVM *,const char *,const char *,const char *); rc=VERR_NO_MEMORY
00:00:04.906622 VMSetError: Failed to load R0 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VMMR0.r0: RTCrStoreConvertToOpenSslCertStack failed: \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0
00:00:04.906637 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\VM.cpp(567) int __cdecl vmR3CreateU(struct UVM *,unsigned int,int (__cdecl *)(struct UVM *,struct VM *,void *),void *); rc=VERR_NO_MEMORY
00:00:04.906639 VMSetError: Failed to load VMMR0.r0
00:00:04.906846 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Failed to load R0 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VMMR0.r0: RTCrStoreConvertToOpenSslCertStack failed: \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0 (VERR_NO_MEMORY).
00:00:04.906915 Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_NO_MEMORY)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-8
00:00:04.907172 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:04.951029 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_NO_MEMORY, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:05.451100 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:05.451138 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up (Display::setVideoModeHint)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:05.451484 GUI: Aborting startup due to power up progress issue detected...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough free RAM on the host machine - I had this error when my RAM was completely maxed out. After freeing up some memory, the VM started just fine.